# determine image width and height to fit inside a frame xamarin.forms

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, frame

i am creating a xamarin.forms app.  i have a grid with 2 columns and the rows are populated according to the number of books a student has, for example if he has 6 books, there will be 3 rows. in each cell i want to put the image of the book cover inside a frame in which if the frame is tapped, the student can view the book's content. the thing is i want the image to appear properly inside the frame, not cropped and not stretched. in addition, i don't want the frames to be too small that i might get a lot of white space between the frames. what can i do to make the image appear properly inside the frame?

i wrote this code. the images fit properly in the frame, but the frames appear thin according to the images' widths with a lot of white space between the grid columns in my ipad, and the ammount of white space changes accoring to the screen size:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nbofColumns; i++)
            {
                lessonsGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star) });
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < nbofRows; j++)
            {
                lessonsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star) });
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var listdata = list[i];

                Image image = new Image
                {

                    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                   
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    Margin = 10
                };
                image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("LearningWithCassidyThird.icons." + listdata.ImageUrl);
                Frame frame = new Frame
                {
                    HasShadow = true,

                    BorderColor = Color.Gray,
                    CornerRadius = 5,
                    Margin = 5,
                    Padding = -2,
                   
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    ClassId = listdata.Name,
                    Content = image

                };

                var AddTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();

                AddTap.Tapped += async (s, evt) =>
                {
                    // await DisplayAlert("d", grade, "g");
                    var stack = this.Navigation.NavigationStack;
                    if (stack[stack.Count - 1].GetType() != typeof(lessonsPage))
                    {
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new lessonsPage(grade, frame.ClassId));
                    }
                };




                frame.GestureRecognizers.Add(AddTap);
                lessonsGrid.Children.Add(frame, i % (int)nbofColumns, i / (int)nbofColumns);
```

how can i solve this issue?

Comment: are all of your images the same aspect ratio?

Comment: You might have to set HeightRequest and WidthRequest on each image. I suspect having "Frame" between the outer grid and the inner image causes the image to not calculate the available size.

Comment: @Jason the dimensions of one of the images are 1132x1600 and the rest are 1131x1600, so i guess the aspect ratio is close but not the same right?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i need to do something that would make the images appear properly on any screen with different sizes, so i don't know how to choose the heights and widths to make this happen

Comment: Do the images look good, for size and spacing, without the frame? I know it won’t be the look you want, but this will help determine what exactly is happening re image layout. Two screenshots, one with frame, one without, would be helpful.